# Add amount from one row to amount in a different row with same primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a query where I would like to add the amount from one row to the amount of another row. Basically for any specific LLW, wherever WT_CPDS = 'ASBESTOS' and the first digit of FYP_NUM is not 5 or 6, id like to add the Obligation amount of this field to the obligation amount where WT_CPDS = 'CONTIN'.

The field "MATCH" can also be used as a primary key since it is a unique identifier. I am using Oracle SQL Developer. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 SELECT LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS, SUM(OBLIGATION) AS OBLIGATION, LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS AS MATCH
 FROM OBS_MASTER OB, LLW LLW
 WHERE LLW.LLW = OB.PROJECT AND  LLW.LLW = '049039' 
 GROUP BY LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS, LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS
 ORDER BY WT_CPDS

 Actual Result:

   LLW      FYP_NUM     WT_CPDS     OBLIGATION      MATCH
  049039    4.090       ASBESTOS    14175.3         049039ASBESTOS
  049039    4.090       CONTIN      384812.65       049039CONTIN
  049039    4.090       DESIGN      21990.06        049039DESIGN
  049039    4.090       SCOPE       8209.68         049039SCOPE

 Expected Result:

  LLW       FYP_NUM     WT_CPDS     OBLIGATION      MATCH
  049039    4.090       ASBESTOS    14175.3         049039ASBESTOS
  049039    4.090       CONTIN      398987.95       049039CONTIN
  049039    4.090       DESIGN      21990.06        049039DESIGN
  049039    4.090       SCOPE       8209.68         049039SCOPE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS,
       (SUM(OBLIGATION) +
        (CASE WHEN WT_CPDS = 'CONTIN' AND FYP_NUM NOT IN (5, 6)
              THEN SUM(CASE WHEN WT_CPDS = 'ASBESTOS' THEN OBLIGATION ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY  LLW)
              ELSE 0
        END) AS OBLIGATION,
       LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS AS MATCH
FROM OBS_MASTER OB JOIN
     LLW LLW
     ON LLW.LLW = OB.PROJECT AND  LLW.LLW = '049039'
GROUP BY LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS, LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS
ORDER BY WT_CPDS
```

Comment: This works great and calculated the correct value but im having an issue with other CASE...WHEN statements. Seems like the query stops when then second WHEN statement is true and doesnt proceed to the 3rd one which you just helped with. Any way to Calculate all three WHEN statements?

Comment: OBS.OBLIGATION +
     CASE 
    WHEN OBS.WT_CPDS = 'SCOPE' AND INHOU.CHARGE IS NOT NULL  THEN (INHOU.CHARGE)
    WHEN OBS.WT_CPDS = 'CONTIN' AND OBS.OBLIGATION IS NOT NULL AND OBS.OBLIGATION <> 0 AND ABS(OBS.OBLIGATION) > 0 THEN (-AWD.AWARD)
    WHEN OBS.WT_CPDS = 'CONTIN' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN OBS.WT_CPDS = 'ASBESTOS' AND SUBSTR(LLW.FYP_NUM,1,1) NOT IN (6,8) THEN OBS.OBLIGATION ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY LLW.LLW)
ELSE CASE WHEN OBS.OBLIGATION IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
END AS OBLIGATION,

Comment: Sorry about the messy query, im not sure how to make it into code format for a comment

Comment: @Manny . . . I think I fixed the answer.  I clearly missed the condition on `FYP_NUM` the first time.

Comment: I had already added that and i've figured out the issue. Just one last question. In my original query i was filtering on a particular LLW for testing purposes. When i remove the LLW filter and look at the entire population i get an error: ORA-01722: invalid number. Do you how i can get past this? If i remove the Windows function the case statement stops working and returns the else value, in this case 0. Thank you!

Comment: @Manny . . . Based on what is in the query, that suggests that `FYP_NUM` or `OBLIGATION` is stored as a string and not a number.  You would use a `WHERE` clause or `CASE` expression to filter out the invalid values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outer query and `CASE ..WHEN` statement as follow:

```
SELECT LLW, FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS,
       OBLIGATION + CASE WHEN WT_CPDS = 'CONTIN' THEN SUM(CASE 
           WHEN TRUNC(FYP_NUM) NOT IN (5,6) AND WT_CPDS = 'ASBESTOS'
           THEN OBLIGATION END) OVER (PARTITION BY LLW) ELSE 0 END AS OBLIGATION, 
        MATCH
FROM
  (SELECT LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS, 
          SUM(OBLIGATION) AS OBLIGATION, LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS AS MATCH
     FROM OBS_MASTER OB, LLW LLW
    WHERE LLW.LLW = OB.PROJECT AND  LLW.LLW = '049039' 
 GROUP BY LLW.LLW, LLW.FYP_NUM, WT_CPDS, LLW.LLW || OB.WT_CPDS
  )
 ORDER BY WT_CPDS;
```

Cheers!!